# Stopping IIS service

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-service

I've got IIS setup on my computer. I stopped it in order to start wamp/apache. so, I stopped the World Wide Web service in the services MMC snap-in and started wamp. but I still can't get wamp login page and instead get IIS home page.

how do I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

From an elevated command prompt you can run `iisreset stop`